# Не понимаю, почему gulp не копирует изображения формата png и svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, scss

Вот gulpfile.js:

```html
let project_folder = require('path').basename(__dirname);
let source_folder = '#src';

let fs = require('fs');

let path = {
    build:{
        html: project_folder+'/',
        css: project_folder+'/css/',
        js: project_folder+'/js/',
        img: project_folder+'/img/',
        fonts: project_folder+'/fonts/',
    },
    src:{
        html: [source_folder+'/*.html', '!' + source_folder + '/_*.html'],
        css: source_folder+'/scss/style.scss',
        js: source_folder+'/js/script.js',
        img: source_folder+'/img/**/*.{jpg, png, svg, gif, ico, webp}',
        fonts: source_folder+'/fonts/*.ttf',
    },

    watch:{
        html: source_folder+'/**/*.html',
        css: source_folder+'/scss/**/*.scss',
        js: source_folder+'/js/**/*.js',
        img: source_folder+'/img/**/*.{jpg, png, svg, gif, ico, webp}',
    },

    clean:'./' + project_folder + '/'

}

let { src, dest } = require('gulp'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    browsersync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
    del = require('del'),
    scss = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    group_media = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries'),
    clean_css = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default,
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp'),
    webphtml = require('gulp-webp-html'),
    webpcss = require('gulp-webpcss'),
    ttf2woff = require('gulp-ttf2woff'),
    ttf2woff2 = require('gulp-ttf2woff2');
    
    

function browserSync(){
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir:'./' + project_folder + '/'
        },

        port:3000,
        notify:false,
    });
}

function html(){
    return src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(webphtml())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function css(){
    return src(path.src.css)
        .pipe(
            scss({
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
            })
        )
        .pipe(
            group_media()
        )
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                overrideBrowserslist: ['last 5 versions'],
                cascade: true
            })
        )
        .pipe(webpcss())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(
            clean_css()
        )
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname:'.min.css'
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function js(){
    return src(path.src.js)
        .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(
            uglify()
        )
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname:'.min.js'
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function images(){
    return src(path.src.img)
        .pipe(
            webp({
                quality: 70
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(src(path.src.img))
        .pipe(
            imagemin({
                progressive:true,
                svgoPlugins:[{ removeViewBox:false }],
                interlaced:true,
                optimizatipnLevel: 3
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function fonts(){
    src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(ttf2woff())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));

    return src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(ttf2woff2())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));
}


    function fontsStyle(params) {

        let file_content = fs.readFileSync(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss');
        if (file_content == '') {
        fs.writeFile(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss', '', cb);
        return fs.readdir(path.build.fonts, function (err, items) {
        if (items) {
        let c_fontname;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        let fontname = items[i].split('.');
        fontname = fontname[0];
        if (c_fontname != fontname) {
        fs.appendFile(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss', '@include font("' + fontname + '", "' + fontname + '", "400", "normal");\r\n', cb);
        }
        c_fontname = fontname;
        }
        }
        })
        }
        }


function cb(){}

function watchFiles(){
    gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.css], css);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.js], js);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.img], images);
}

function clean(){
    return del(path.clean);
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(js, css, html, images, fonts), fontsStyle);
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);


exports.fontsStyle = fontsStyle;
exports.fonts = fonts;
exports.images = images;
exports.js = js;
exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

Comment: `gulp.src(['src/icons/**', 'src/libs/**'], {base: './src/'}).pipe(gulp.dest('build'));`

Comment: Уберите пробелы

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, спасибо, там реально пробелы надо было убрать и все